# Lost Adobe Creative Suite License Key: Options?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

Background: I have a legitimate Adobe CS (I believe it is version 5.5) installed about 5 years ago on a Windows 7 machine. I have plans to upgrade to a newer machine and newer Windows.

Problem: I can't find the original license key paperwork; and I don't have disks; it was an online installation method.

Question: Is there any way for me to transfer my Adobe CS installation to a new machine?

(the most desired program is the full version of Adobe Acrobat)

Comment: If it was purchased online it would be linked to your Adobe account.  **Contact Adobe for assistance.**

Comment: You might be able to retrieve the key with something like Belarc Advisor.